# How to overwrite asp-action in a form - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form like this and i want to change the asp-action using javascript but the code below does not overwrite. What could i be doing wrong here ?

**HTML**

```
<form class="myform" id="myform" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Users" method="get">
  <button type="submit">
</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.action = 'Index';
    this.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `setAttribute` since asp-action is an ASP specific argument.

```
this.setAttribute("asp-action","Index");
```